# Simple Django Image Upload - Image file not saving

Tags: django, file-upload, django-forms, django-uploads

Right I'm learning how to do a simple image upload form to upload an image to MEDIA_ROOT. The form renders fine, I get no errors, but the file is not showing up in the MEDIA_ROOT directory. If followed the documentation example and can't get it to work and I know it is because I have not understood django file upload handeling properly. So here is my code:

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class UploadImageForm(forms.Form):
    image = forms.ImageField()
```

views.py

```
def merchant_image_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            FileUploadHandler(request.FILES['image'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/dashboard/gallery')
    else:
        form = UploadImageForm()
    return render_to_response('gallery.html', RequestContext(request, {'form': form}))
```

template file

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block main %}
    <form action="{% url scvd.views.merchant_image_upload %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.image }}
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Hopefully that's sufficient info to get some help. Please let me know what else I can provide. Thank you, I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't need to attach it to a model as Matt S states, request.FILES has all the data for the image if your form is set up correctly.

You need to make sure use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your  element, as the docs state here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files-to-a-form

Aside from that, read the docs about file uploads: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/

All you need is well documented there. Hope this helps!

**EDIT OP requested more information on File Uploads**

From the docs:

> Most of the time, you'll simply pass the file data from request into
>   the form as described in Binding uploaded files to a form. This would
>   look something like:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

# Imaginary function to handle an uploaded file.
from somewhere import handle_uploaded_file

def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render_to_response('upload.html', {'form': form})
```

And they have an example of how you could write the `handle_uploaded_file` function:

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    destination = open('some/file/name.txt', 'wb+')
    for chunk in f.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)
    destination.close()
```

Comment: Thank Jordan. I had forgotten to add the proper enctype. I have done that now. I had also forgotten to install PIL which is need required for the usage of the ImageField. I had followed the django documentation for file upload and the above code is what I came up with. Now I don't see what I am doing wrong, but I feel like it has to do my usage of the FileUploadHandler provided by django. Can you provide some insight into using the handler properly? I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have your  files uploaded and shows in request.FILES, your form MUST contain enctype="multipart/form-data" as shown below:

```
<form action="{% url scvd.views.merchant_image_upload %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.image }}
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You need to attach it to a model (as an [ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/files/)) as it's not being saved anywhere presently. It may be handled without any issues right now but it gets discarded after the view returns.</strike>

Never mind, I didn't realize models were unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for the response Matt. I created the following model:      class Gallery(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='gallery')                       Now how do I attach this model to the form and how does that relate to the django FileUploadHandler?